# callback on azure key vault

Tags: node.js, express, azure-keyvault

I am using azure-keyvault to store secret, I would like to use the secret in my configuration file, but facing some problem on callback. The problem is the secret is not return before calling bookshelf.js, and password is **undefined**:

**config.js:**

```
var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
module.exports = require('./env/' + environment + '.js');
```

**keyvault.js:**

```
var sqlPassword =  function(){
      var promise = new Promise(
        function resolver(resolve, reject) {
            var secretId = secrectUri + 'secrets/password';
            client.getSecret(secretId, function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                resolve(result.value);
            });
        }
      );
};

module.export = {
    sqlPassword: sqlPassword()
};
```

**env/development.js**

```
var secret = require('../keyvault');

module.exports = {
    db: {
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
            host     : '127.0.0.1',
            user     : 'sa',
            password : secret.sqlPassword,
            database : 'avin',
            charset  : 'utf8'
        },
        debug: true
    }
};
```

**bookshelf.js**

```
var config = require('./config');

var knex = require('knex')(config.db);
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
bookshelf.plugin('registry');

module.exports = bookshelf;
```

**app.js**

```
var config = require('./config/config');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bookshelf = require('./config/bookshelf');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!');
});
```

Comment: issue with the `promise` in keyvault.js . You declared it, but never called it.

Comment: Hi Sharma, tq for the answer, but the password is Promise object, and looks like the  client.getSecret is not call...

Comment: yes, actually when you create the `db`, at that time promise is in pending state. Solution can be fetch the password first and then load it in db object.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm having the same difficulties. Using this concept, how can I continue to run the rest of the code when the KeyVault values are finally returned?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code.

First, you declared the `promise` object, but never called it.

**keyvault.js**

```
var sqlPassword =  function(){
  //promise code
  return promise;
};

module.exports = {
  sqlPassword: sqlPassword
};
```

**env/development.js**

```
module.exports = {
   db: {
      //some other code
      connection: {
        password : secret.sqlPassword().then(function(result){
           return result;
        }),
      },
      //some other code
   }
};
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: I tried this, but I just dont know why the password is a Promise object, instead the password.

Answer (score 0):

The package `azure-keyvault` has been deprecated in favor of the new packages to deal with Keyvault keys, secrets and certificates separately. For your scenario, you can use the new [@azure/keyvault-secrets](http://npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets) package.

The methods in the new package use promises rather than callbacks. That should simplify your code quite a bit. To move you application from the older package, you can see the [migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/keyvault-secrets/migration-guide.md) which lists the major differences and what to look out for.

Main changes to your code would be:

```js
var sqlPassword =  async function(){
  const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  const client = new SecretClient(KEY_VAULT_URI, credential);
  const secret = await client.getSecret(secretName);
  return secret.value;
};
```

To understand how the DefaultAzureCredentiual works, see the [readme for @azure/identity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity)